# creating xml file

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have created a xml like this below  !!!

I'm reading files from folder I have collected all files details and I need to prepare a xml file ...

Can any one help me to create xml ..!! please

```
   Xml = New XmlDocument()
   Xml.AppendChild(Xml.CreateElement("ROOT"))
   Dim xmlroot As XmlElement = Xml.DocumentElement
   Dim InstXml As XmlElement = Xml.CreateElement("ERRORLOG")
   SwiftFileName = Errfile.ToString()
   InstXml.SetAttribute("SWIFT_FILENAME", SwiftFileName)
   Status = "SUCCESS"
   InstXml.SetAttribute("RESULT", Status)
   Errortext = "NULL"
   InstXml.SetAttribute("ERRORTEXT", Errortext)
   xmlroot.AppendChild(InstXml)
```

Comment: Create XML as in saving it to disc?

Comment: This should be helpful: [Create a New XML File Using XmlDocument](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/21168). The code is in C#, you may be to convert it to VB (not major differences though).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is with the xmlserializer.

Create a class wich is serialable:

```
<System.Serializable()> _ 
Public Class ClassToXML
    Public ErrorLog As String
    Public SwithFileName As String
    Status As String
End Class
```

And save it with serialize and read it back with deserialize
see: [msdn arctivle](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316730)

With attributes you can change the serialization of fields and properties.

Good luck